# How do I internationalize API errors in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, spring-rest

I was able to internationalize a controller web page request with

```
@RequestMapping(value="/image")
public String image(@RequestHeader(name=HEADER_CONSTANTS.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, required=false) String al) {
```

In the parameter list. However I tried to put it in a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and it didn't work.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages="com.example.apis")
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiException(ApiException ex, @RequestHeader(name=HEADER_CONSTANTS.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, required=false) String al) {
```

> 2019-05-13 21:59:59.193  WARN 16052 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.apis.RestExceptionHandler.handleApiException(com.example.apis.ApiException,java.lang.String)
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 1 in protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.apis.RestExceptionHandler.handleApiException(com.example.apis.ApiException,java.lang.String): No suitable resolver for argument 1 of type 'java.lang.String'

It works without the `@RequestHeader` parameter. How can I get the client's `Accept-Language` HTTP header in the exception handler for JSON API requests?

Spring Boot 1.5.20

Comment: As a general note, please make sure not to internationalize actual error codes, only human-directed explanatory information. Also note that it's more idiomatic to use the values in `HttpHeaders` than to redefine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation for @ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

It is invalid syntax, look at the rules of method signatures. You can use `WebRequest` to get the `Header`

```
@ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiException(ApiException ex, WebRequest request) {
     request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);
}
```

Annotation for handling exceptions in specific handler classes and/or handler methods.

Handler methods which are annotated with this annotation are allowed to have very flexible signatures. They may have parameters of the following types, in arbitrary order:

- An exception argument: declared as a general Exception or as a more specific exception. This also serves as a mapping hint if the annotation itself does not narrow the exception types through its value().
- Request and/or response objects (typically from the Servlet API). You may choose any specific request/response type, e.g. ServletRequest / HttpServletRequest.
- Session object: typically HttpSession. An argument of this type will enforce the presence of a corresponding session. As a consequence, such an argument will never be null. Note that session access may not be thread-safe, in particular in a Servlet environment: Consider switching the "synchronizeOnSession" flag to "true" if multiple requests are allowed to access a session concurrently.
- WebRequest or NativeWebRequest. Allows for generic request parameter access as well as request/session attribute access, without ties to the native Servlet API.
- Locale for the current request locale (determined by the most specific locale resolver available, i.e. the configured LocaleResolver in a Servlet environment).
  InputStream / Reader for access to the request's content. This will be the raw InputStream/Reader as exposed by the Servlet API.
- OutputStream / Writer for generating the response's content. This will be the raw OutputStream/Writer as exposed by the Servlet API.
- Model as an alternative to returning a model map from the handler method. Note that the provided model is not pre-populated with regular model attributes and therefore always empty, as a convenience for preparing the model for an exception-specific view

Comment: Using `@RequestHeader` is fine on controller advice.

Comment: but he can also use `WebRequest` to get the header value right  and it will be helpful if you can say why it throws an exception@chrylis

Comment: This works too. I see I can just directly get the `Locale` as an injected parameter also! Don't listen to chylis; they did not read the question.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is the locale of the current user, you should register a `LocaleResolver` and then get the locale from `LocaleContextHolder`.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    // Registering accept-header Locale Resolver with default Locale.US
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);

    return localeResolver;
}
```

Then you can get the locale in your exception handler by calling `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`.

Comment: Or injecting via method parameter.

Comment: This does work. @chrylis No injecting via method parameter does not work, which prompted this question in the first place. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Chloe [The documentation for `@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) *explicitly* lists `Locale` as a supported parameter. If that doesn't work, then it's definitely worth filing a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following based on Deadpool's answer. I got exceptions (`org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException`) if the language bundle did not contain the translation for a given message key. I wish it was possible to default to English if the `.properties` file does not contain the translation, in one line.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleApiException(ApiException ex, Locale locale) {
    String defaultMessage = messages.getMessage(ex.errorMessage, ex.errorArgument, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String localErrorMessage = messages.getMessage(ex.errorMessage, ex.errorArgument, defaultMessage, locale);
```